# How to update a menu link created with MenuLinkContent::create()?

Tags: 8, navigation

I know how to search for menu items created with `*.links.menu.yml`:

```
$menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link');
$menu_links = $menu_link_manager->loadLinksByRoute('user.page');
foreach ($menu_links as $menu_link) {
  // Do something
}
```

However I'm looking for a way to search for and update a menu item created with `MenuLinkContent::create()`:

```
$home_new = MenuLinkContent::create(array(
  'title' => t('Home'),
  'link' => array('uri' => 'internal:/'),
  'menu_name' => 'main',
));
$home_new->save();
```

After creating this menu item, how do I look it back up again to modify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remember the id after saving the menu link

```
$id = $home_new->id();
```

You can load it directly:

```
$link = MenuLinkContent::load($id);
```

If you don't know the id, you can load the menu link by a property:

```
$links = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')
  ->loadByProperties(['title' => 'Home']);

if ($link = reset($links)) {
  // found a link with title "Home"
}
```

Comment: Minor fix: if ($link = reset($links)) {

Comment: To follow up on this, if you have the link path, you can get it with the `link__uri` property, e.g.


`$links = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')->loadByProperties(['link_uri' => 'internal:/contact-us']);`